Cookies are coming undefined after deploying on vercel
I've middleware checkAuth which checks is user logged in  or not based on the token in cookies, It works perfectly on local but when I deployed it on vercel cookies are not coming it prints undefined.
This is my local log in terminal
This are the logs on the vercel
I tried using withCredentials: true, but still not working

Have you checked whether cookies are being sent?
